# Code to enter records in mysql table via tkinter not giving the correct output

Tags: python-3.x

I want to enter records in mysql table via tkinter, but whenever I run my program it enters `NULL` in the columns in my table. Can someone correct my code?

`val1` and `val2` have the data stored that is entered in the tkinter entry, this I have already verified.

```
e1=Entry(window)
e1.place(x=100,y=50)

e2=Entry(window)
e2.place(x=100,y=90)

import mysql.connector

m = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="12@4",database="s")
mc = m.cursor()

def fun():
    val1=e1.get()
    val2=e2.get()

    mc.execute("insert into email(Name,Email) values(val1,val2)")
    m.commit()

    from tkinter import messagebox
    messagebox.showinfo("Congratulations", "You Are Now Rich")

b = Button(window, text="Submit",command=fun, bg="orange", activeforeground="magenta")
```

This code enters `NULL` in my mysql table and not entries made through tkinter.

Comment: I'm not sure but I feel that you're passing hard coded values and not the values you're expecting. also value1 is not something SQL knows I guess you miss the quotes for hardcoded values. have a look at https://www.guru99.com/insert-into.html

Comment: Could you use f strings to pass the values, ie `f"insert into email(Name,Email) values({val1},{val2})"`, rather than hard coded ones as Computer Aided Trading Systems said? Depending on the type of data your database is expecting, you may need to put quotes in there as well, ie `f"insert into email(Name,Email) values('{val1}','{val2}')"`...

Comment: Well I am just a beginner(school student) and even know what are hardcoded values.